# Visual Dialplan + Asterisk Pbx

Tags: ip, asterisk, voip, pbx

i have problem with my dial plan. I am using some php codes for looping and i am getting dynamic data in array. Ex: One username have maybe 2 or more accounts. I am getting account names and i am choosing a account.

i am using background option in loop for playing account names and context. When i press button 2,3 or 4 dial plan going to context and context pattern. So its working. But button 1 not working. I am getting extension error. I have no idea about why?

```
[2015-09-15 17:30:31] WARNING[26175][C-0000077d]: pbx.c:6696 __ast_pbx_run: Invalid extension '1', but no rule 'i' or 'e' in context 'Net-IVR-EN-ID'
```

and this is my config file;

```
exten => multi_wdsl,n,AGI(n_get_adres_wdsl.php,ara=${acc_number})
exten => multi_wdsl,n(lbl_Net-IVR-EN-ID_16),Set(counterplus=${MATH(${counter}+1,i)})
exten => multi_wdsl,n(lbl_Net-IVR-EN-ID_17),Set(TIMEOUT(response)=10)
exten => multi_wdsl,n,Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=10)
exten => multi_wdsl,n,Background(${ses${counter}}&/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/e/i/${counterplus},,en,WDSL_MENU)
exten => multi_wdsl,n,Set(counter=${MATH(${counter}+1,i)})
exten => multi_wdsl,n,GotoIf($["${wdsl_total}" = "${counter}"]?:lbl_Net-IVR-EN-ID_16)
exten => multi_wdsl,n,Set(TIMEOUT(response)=10)
exten => multi_wdsl,n,Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=10)
exten => multi_wdsl,n,Background(5sec&custom/custom/se,,en,WDSL_MENU)
exten => multi_wdsl,n,Goto(Net-IVR-EN-ID,multi_wdsl,1)
exten => i,1,Goto(multi_wdsl,lbl_Net-IVR-EN-ID_17)
exten => multi_wdsl__,1,Read(ir,custom/custom/ir,1,,5,10)
exten => multi_wdsl__,n,GotoIf($["${ir}" = "*"]?:lbl_Net-IVR-EN-ID_18)
exten => multi_wdsl__,n,Goto(Net-IVR-EN-ID,multi_wdsl,1)
exten => multi_wdsl__,n(lbl_Net-IVR-EN-ID_18),GotoIf($["${ir}" = "0"]?:lbl_Net-IVR-EN-ID_19)
exten => multi_wdsl__,n,Goto(Net-IVR-EN,multi_wdsl,1)
exten => multi_wdsl__,n(lbl_Net-IVR-EN-ID_19),Playback(custom/se/wrong_button)
exten => multi_wdsl__,n,Goto(Net-IVR-EN,multi_wdsl,1)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dialplan you shown not have any option for 1,2,3 or 4

Background app usually used like this:

```
; this one just play file, not collect any input
exten => multi_wdsl,n,Background(5sec&custom/custom/se,,en,WDSL_MENU)
exten => multi_wdsl,n,WaitExten(5); on this stage it wait for input and go extension you entered
exten  => 1,1,Noop(do something for 1)
exten  => 2,1,Noop(do somethign for 2)
exten  => i,1,Noop(invalid input);
```

Also you have Read app, which play and collect digit.

So background app not collect anything. Issue is not background app.

Comment: 2,3 and 4 are working. i found solution without read app. i added new exten it is name is 1 in the Net-IVR-EN context and i used goto option for multi_wdsl and its going to parent 1 now. But i thing this method is illogical... Anyway its working, i will send my working answer in one business day.

Comment: Sure it working, but none of it in dialplan you show for us.